# "(generated application controller)" displayed instead of value contents in Handlebars "#each" helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm working with my `application.hbs` template in EmberJS, and working to create a dynamic dropdown menu that is populated by the model contents. My route/model is defined like:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      dictionaries: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
      test: 'Value'
    });
  }
});
```

And in my template, if I use `{{model.test}}`, then it prints `"Value"` successfully. **However:** When I try to build a list using the values of `model.dictionaries`, both attempts fail, albeit *differently*.

This method:

```
{{#each model.dictionaries}}
    <li><a href="#">{{this}}</a></li>
{{else}}
    <li><a href="#" style="font-style: italic;">No values</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Builds a list with 3 entries, but their contents are:

```
<li><a href="#">(generated application controller)</a></li>
<li><a href="#">(generated application controller)</a></li>
<li><a href="#">(generated application controller)</a></li>
```

And if I try instead to assign each item a name:

```
{{#each dict in model.dictionaries}}
    <li><a href="#">{{dict}}</a></li>
{{else}}
    <li><a href="#" style="font-style: italic;">No values</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Then **no** values are displayed, resulting in:

```
<li><a href="#" style="font-style: italic;">No values</a></li>
```

What mistake am I making in attempting to iterate the model-provided array?

Comment: where is the `{{#if}}` that goes with your `{{else}}`?

Comment: The `{{else}}` is automatically executed if there are no items in the array being iterated: http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the [`each`](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/) helper properly. Ember actually uses HTMLBars, which has a syntax similar to handlebars, but with some differences introduced to make data binding easier. This should fix your issue I believe:

```
{{#each model.dictionaries as |somename|}}
    <li><a href="#">{{somename}}</a></li>
{{else}}
    <li><a href="#" style="font-style: italic;">No values</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Explanation of the errors:

- In your first attempt, you display `this`. In a template, `this` is a special name that refers to the controller or component that the template is attached to. Here, it is an auto-generated controller, thus what you see (that's the result of calling `toString` on the generated controller).
- In your second attempt… well it should be a syntax error, but it seems the helper does not check the number of arguments it receive. So no error, but it silently ignores additional arguments. So here, you end up invoking the `each` helper, with 3 arguments : variable `dict` (which is undefined), variable `in` (which is undefined) and variable `models.dictionaries` (which is your list, but ignored by the helper).

  As `dict` is undefined, the `else` block is executed.